# passing data from the element to the loader in react router dom 6.14

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

1. I couldn't find a way to pass props from the context to the loader function (or even from the element that use that loader )

- i dont want pass the data as params due to in some cases it could be objects.

2. currently i can create spinner in each element that loaded by the router , but i guess there is a way to apply spinner from the router loader itself , couldnt find a way

This is the Index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import router from "./Routs/Routs";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { SiteProvider } from "./hooks/useContext";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SiteProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </SiteProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and the router

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/products/:category",
        element: <ProductsMain />,
        loader: getItems,
      }
    ],
  }
]);
```

the getItems function:

```
export async function getItems(request: any) {
  const body = {
    some data//:how do i pass a data to the body from context or Other element as props?,
  };
  try {
    const url = `${urlBE}/products/${request.params.category}`;
    // console.log(request);
    return await serverAPI(url, body, "success");
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

And now in the ProductData i can use the data from the loader ass follow:

```
  const { data, message, error }: any = useLoaderData();
  useEffect(() => {
    data && setProducts(data);
  }, [data]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of implementing something more globally accessible like Redux where you can just import the store object and access current state or dispatch actions my suggestion here would be to use a Context Consumer to access and pass the context value to the router so it can be passed to loader functions.

The following example may be close to what you are looking for.

```js
export async getItems = (contextValue: SiteContextType) => (request: any) => {
  const body = {
    // some data accessible via provided context value
  };

  try {
    const url = `${urlBE}/products/${request.params.category}`;
    return await serverAPI(url, body, "success");
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

```
const router = (contextValue: SiteContextType) => createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/products/:category",
        element: <ProductsMain />,
        loader: getItems(contextValue),
      }
    ],
  }
]);
```

```js
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SiteProvider>
      <SiteContext.Consumer>
        {value => <RouterProvider router={router(value)} />}
      </SiteContext.Consumer>
    </SiteProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: first time ever i found a usage for context. consumer. it working perfectly!
now i wonder the side effects of this approach if exist.

Comment: i back to this issue again due to any update of the context will trigger rerendreing of the router , and rerender of useLoaderData which will invoke the loader again and again. 

Didnt found a solution yet for that

Comment: @Bennyh961 Sorry, went on vacation for a bit. You might try a refactor that creates a "container" component that uses the `useContext` hook to access the context value and caches it in a React ref that is updated when the context value changes. The router will be similar to that in my answer, but memoized with the `useMemo` hook with appropriate dependencies. Does this make sense or do you need to see an example? If you need more help it might be more beneficial to create a new post for the newer issue you need help with. If you do this then please feel free to ping me in a comment here.